# Distribute the load of data on two kafka consumer using kafka.net client

Tags: producer-consumer, kafka-consumer-api

How I can divide the load of data on my two kafka consumer using kafka .net client.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with .net client. However, according to the Github page (github.com/Jroland/kafka-net) it seems, consumer groups are not supported yet.

However, it seems you can use whitelist to read only certain partitions. Thus, you can distribute the load manually:

From https://github.com/Jroland/kafka-net#consumer-1:

> If no whitelist is provided then all partitions will be consumed creating one KafkaConnection for each partition leader